# Nginx config file

Tags: nginx

How does nginx figure I have a conflicting server name?

`[warn] conflicting server name "" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored nginx.`

I wouldn't care, except it only seems to be serving files from project.ca and completely ignores projectfinancial.com...

```
server {
        root /var/www/project/infrastructure/project/static-sites/projectlabswebsite;
        index index.html
        server_name projectfinancial.com *.projectfinancial.com;
        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to index.html
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }
}

server {
        root /var/www/project/infrastructure/project/static-sites/project-website;
        index index.html
        server_name project.ca *.project.ca;
        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to index.html
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

There is a missing semi colon after index index.html

And for those interested, you can set server_name to `.project.ca` instead of `project.ca *.project.ca` as they are both the same.